# Jquery script breaks down throwing syntax error on live server only

Tags: jquery, html, syntax-error

I got an html template that I intend to use. The theme owners example site as well as my local sandbox server work perfectly. When I install this to my live server, the plugin.min.js file throws an error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Then of course it all breaks down since this file appears to install the other js files.

I've checked the line in question and it does actually close with ')'

Is there anything that might occur or be set within the live server that could be corrupting this?

You can go to [masstactical.com](http://masstactical.com) to see the error in action. I use a2hosting. local server is xampp.

[image]

Comment: there is no error in console.

Comment: What do we have to do to trigger the error? Have you tried installing the non-minified version of the plugin library?

Comment: I havent found the non minified script yet. I'm looking for it now. All you have to do is open the webpage which wont load other than the black background color.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned that Santosh. Is there a way to modify this question to why Google Chrome is making this an error on the live server? IE works fine on live and sandbox. Chrome works on sandbox but not live.

Comment: @Barmar, found a unminifytool and uploaded an unminified version. This Fixed the error issue. Now, on to figuring out why the css is all wonky.

Comment: I went to your site using Chrome, and didn't get an error.

Comment: Error is fixed. For some reason it did need to be unminified. However, this has totally hijacked the css I added so i'm trying to figure all that out. IE no longer works in live server either. I'll continue playing with this. I appreciate the help.